# installing ncdf R package

Tags: r, xcode, failed-installation

I have been trying to install the ncdf R package. I have searched answers and attempted to solve the problem, but it looks like it's the time for me to ask for some help here.

I downloaded ncdf_1.6.5.tar.gz from this page ("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/ncdf/), saved it in Download folder.

As it does not have a NAMESPACE file, I untar-ed the file and  did the following

```
cd Downloads
cd ncdf
echo 'exportPattern( "." )' > NAMESPACE
cd ..
tar -zcf ncdf.tar.gz ncdf
```

Then I tried to install the package by this command

```
R CMD INSTALL -l /Users/xyc/Downloads/ncdf.tar.gz
```

It gave me this

```
ARGUMENT 'CDM' __ignor'e__

ARGUMENT 'INSTALL' __ignor'e__

AVIS : option inconnue '-l'

ARGUMENT 'ncdf.tar.gz' __ignor'e__


R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28) -- "Short Summer"
Copyright (C) 2017 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)

R est un logiciel libre livré sans AUCUNE GARANTIE.
Vous pouvez le redistribuer sous certaines conditions.
Tapez 'license()' ou 'licence()' pour plus de détails.

Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Tapez 'demo()' pour des démonstrations, 'help()' pour l'aide
en ligne ou 'help.start()' pour obtenir l'aide au format HTML.
Tapez 'q()' pour quitter R.
```

Obviously, this did not install the package.

I tried to install in RStudio by

```
install.packages("ncdf.tar.gz", lib = "/Users/xyc/Downloads", repos = NULL)
```

It showed me

```
* installing *source* package ‘ncdf’ ...
checking for nc-config... /opt/local/bin/nc-config
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating src/Makevars
** libs
make: error: unable to find utility "make", not a developer tool or in PATH
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘ncdf’
* removing ‘/Users/xyc/Downloads/ncdf’
* restoring previous ‘/Users/xyc/Downloads/ncdf’
Warning in install.packages :
installation of package ‘ncdf.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Could someone help me here? Thank you very much.

**UPDATE**
Thank you for all your inputs. I downloaded Xcode 9 and a lower version of ncdf and did this

```
$ sudo xcode-select --switch /Users/xyc/Downloads/Xcode.app

$R CMD INSTALL ncdf_1.6.3.tar.gz
```

It gave me 96 warnings and 11 errors. The compilation failed again.

```
* installing to library ‘/Users/hhsieh/Library/R/3.4/library’
* installing *source* package ‘ncdf’ ...
checking for nc-config... /opt/local/bin/nc-config
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating src/Makevars
** libs
clang -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG -
I/opt/local/include  -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c 
._ncdf.c -o ._ncdf.o
._ncdf.c:1:1: warning: null character ignored [-Wnull-character]
<U+0000><U+0005><U+0016><U+0007><U+0000><U+0002><U+0000><U+0000>Mac OS 
X        <U+0000><U+0002><U+0000><U+0000>...
^
._ncdf.c:1:2: error: expected identifier or '('
<U+0000><U+0005><U+0016><U+0007><U+0000><U+0002><U+0000><U+0000>Mac OS 
X        <U+0000><U+0002><U+0000><U+0000>...
    ^
._ncdf.c:1:5: warning: null character ignored [-Wnull-character]
<U+0000><U+0005><U+0016><U+0007><U+0000><U+0002><U+0000><U+0000>Mac OS 
X        <U+0000><U+0002><U+0000><U+0000>...
                            ^
._ncdf.c:1:7: warning: null character ignored [-Wnull-character]
<U+0000><U+0005><U+0016><U+0007><U+0000><U+0002><U+0000><U+0000>Mac OS 
X        <U+0000><U+0002><U+0000><U+0000>...
                                            ^
._ncdf.c:1:8: warning: null character ignored [-Wnull-character]
<U+0000><U+0005><U+0016><U+0007><U+0000><U+0002><U+0000><U+0000>Mac OS 
X        <U+0000><U+0002><U+0000><U+0000>...
                                                    ^
._ncdf.c:1:25: warning: null character ignored [-Wnull-character]
<U+0000><U+0005><U+0016><U+0007><U+0000><U+0002><U+0000><U+0000>Mac OS 
X        <U+0000><U+0002><U+0000><U+0000>...

^
._ncdf.c:1:27: warning: null character ignored [-Wnull-character]
...OS X        <U+0000><U+0002><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000>  <U+0000>
<U+0000><U+0000>2<U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><AC>...
                             ^
._ncdf.c:1:28: warning: null character ignored [-Wnull-character]
...OS X        <U+0000><U+0002><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000>  <U+0000>
<U+0000><U+0000>2<U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><AC>...
                                     ^

(warnings and error cut from here)

96 warnings and 11 errors generated.
make: *** [._ncdf.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘ncdf’
* removing ‘/Users/xyc/Library/R/3.4/library/ncdf’
```

I also tried this

```
$R CMD INSTALL --configure-args="-with-netcdf_incdir=/usr/local/netcdf/4.1.1-gcc/include -with-netcdf_libdir=/usr/local/netcdf/4.1.1-gcc/lib" ncdf_1.6.3.tar.gz
```

which also gave me 96 warnings and 11 errors.

```
96 warnings and 11 errors generated.
make: *** [._ncdf.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘ncdf’
* removing ‘/Users/xyc/Library/R/3.4/library/ncdf’
```

It looks like I still have a problem with XCode.

All suggestions are highly appreciated and welcome.

Thank you...

Comment: Any particular reason you aren't using ncdf4? Also, I don't use Mac so I'm not sure what the development environment is supposed to look like, but I'd guess you need to install xcode and xcode command line tools.

Comment: Thank you,  Eumenedies. I use ncdf because the R package I need to work on now requires ncdf but not ncdf4.

Comment: I also have this while testing xcode command line. `I have this while testing xcode command line. `$ xcode-select --install
xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates`

Comment: Sorry, as I said, I don't use Mac. The error message shows that make isn't correctly configured or, at least, that R can't find it. You should try searching your particular error: `make: error: unable to find utility "make", not a developer tool or in PATH`

Comment: What package are you using that requires `ncdf`?

Comment: Also, the reason your first install command didn't install was because you typed `R CDM INSTALL` instead of `R CMD INSTALL`. That's why it says it is ignoring argument `CDM`.

Comment: Thank you, Eumenedies and Tung, for helping. I would need to reinstall Xcode. Tung, it's a home-made package by a colleague.

Comment: Do you already have rtools? There is something about "make" Missing

Comment: Hi Christoph, do you mean devools? I do have it. `>find_rtools()` returns `TRUE`